# What can be done to prevent multiplayer hacking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a UDP networking project out of curiosity, and I have come to a problem that I can not get my head around. I have researched and understand the basic principles like:

1. Use authoritative servers, and give the client as little authority as possible.
2. Ensure that each client is identified by the server uniquely with its own encrypted key.
3. Deter DDOS attack by inflating response packets.
4. etc..

Most of my knowledge of UDP comes from these wonderful articles: https://gafferongames.com/
; and I am lucky enough to  be using this [library](https://github.com/KillaMaaki/Unity-Netcode.IO), which is based off of the authors own UDP protocol and takes care of most of the authoritative protection.

**Now, here is my question:**

Using a completely authoritative server, it still seems the player would be able to cheat.

- For example:

  For a fighting game, there are two functions on the clients side. `void hit()` and `void hurt`, these are the basic functions that allow the client to stimulate the fight.

  In Scenario 1: The localPlayer hits the other player, and sends this to the server. The server then sends a packet to the client of the player that was hit which would trigger the `hurt()` function. But if the player had edited the files and deleted the hurt function, nothing would happen. The player that had deleted the `hurt()` function would be invincible.

  In Scenario 2: The localPlayer is hit by the other player and calls the `hurt()`, and sends this to the server. The server then sends a packet to the client of the player that hit the localPlayer which would trigger the `hit()` function. But if the localPlayer had edited the files and deleted the `hurt()` function, nothing would happen. The player that had deleted the `hurt()` function would again be invincible.

I could only think of two solutions:

1. If the game ever encountered an error (because a function was deleted and did not exist) disconnect the client from the server.(not that great)
2. This one I just thought of while writing this, and it might be my solution: Store a health variable for each player on the server, and if it reaches 0, ignore any packets that would be impossible if the game was not edited.

That second solution sounds good to me right now, but I am curious as to what you guys do / would do since I am a straight beginner. Glad to hear any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The player that had deleted the `hurt()` function would be invincible.

Not if a "master copy" of the game state is computed by the server. In that case, the player who modifies code will only have their client show an invalid game state, which doesn't help them play.

In general, *everything except player input* must be done by the server, the client only says *what the player chooses to do* and every resulting action/change is performed by the server. That way, the player cannot change anything except what they want to do, which is already under their jurisdiction.

Note that players can still cheat with the aid of tools, such as auto-clickers or aimbots. These forms of cheating are much harder to deal with, since it's hard to tell if someone is receiving inhuman assistance or if they're just a good player.

Comment: For the "master copy", would this be a full unity stimulation of the game with physics and such? Or would my simple solution of health of each player be enough? Also, do you think I would be better off going with a pre-built anticheat? I notice that seems to be the way a lot of company's solve it. And if a company can't be bothered to make their own anti cheat functionality I doubt I. can lol

Comment: The "master copy" contains the entire _state_ of the game -- locations of everything, hit points, current state of physics, etc. Basically, everything you need to know exactly what's going on in the game. The clients have the power to request actions (e.g., shoot a bullet in this direction), but the effect of the action on the state is computed by the server and broadcast to the clients for display.

Comment: What can be done to stimulate smooth movement if everything is authenticated by the server?  I suppose client side prediction could be used, and then if the player is too far from the server's state it would be re positioned. But that would cause a lot of rubber banding (I noticed that running into colliders can sometimes mess things up). Do you know how games get around this?

Comment: @Bureto That's an entirely different question, so you should ask it separately. We try to make every question as focused as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The client should not be deciding wether or not they hit another player, the server should do that.

The client can say, "i shot a bullet in this direction", and then its up to the server to decide, given the game state, wether or not that was a hit. Sure, you should probably have some kind of prediction on the client side tho, depending on the type of game :)

Comment: My game makes use of humanoid avatars and mechanim 3d animation within unity. I came to notice that client side prediction is a must in order for the movement to look smooth. But about what you were saying, do you mean a full unity stimulation of the game on the server for the clients to refer to? I think that would solve a lot of problems for me but I am unsure what my server can handle it. I am using the free tier for AWS do you think it will be fine?

Answer (score 2):

What you described is typical client trust model. Server trusts what client told it.

To completely prevent hack a server trust model is required. Basically the client will send desire action to the server and the server has the ultimate right to decide whether that action is legal or not.

> Client trust example:
>   1. Client A hits Client B
>   2. Client A sends hit package to server
>   3. Server received hit package and broadcast it to everyone
>   4. Client B received the package and calls hurt

to hack it Client A could either edit the hit package to modify the damage amount or keeps sending hit package

> Server trust example:
>   1. Client A used skill 1
>   2. Client A sends cast skill 1 package to server
>   3. Server received cast skill 1 package from client A
>   4. Server validate A's skill 1 CD is available and grant the action. By granting the action server determine B will be hit by that so
>   broadcast (A cast Skill 1, B got hit and B's new HP is xxx)
>   5. Client received broadcast and modify UI

Hack attempt 1: A tries to cast skill 1 when he cannot and server immediately deny that.
Hack attempt 2: A tries to hurt B using package but there is nothing he can send besides the action he could take (I.E. move, skill, attack ect)
Hack attempt 3: A wants to modify the damage but he can't since the damage was calculated on the server

Basically whatever you are simulating and computed on the server side will not be hackable unless they hack your server.

So if you simulate the HP + skill damage then God mode is not possible. If you do server side physics then speed hack is not possible. If you simulate and validate everything then NO hack is possible. (I am not counting script(bot) as hack here since script does not provide game breaking advantage most of the time unless you are making a FPS game and ppl using aim bot)

But this really comes down to the trade off between money spend vs damage done to the game by hack